# Help with comparing to array values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I have developed this code with help from you guys here on stackoverflow.  I have added an extra part to it where it compares two numbers from two different arrays, in this case offhire1 and pro2.
The problem is in my code where I have:

```
(offhire1[i].value > pro2[i].value)
```

It only allows me to contine if the numbers match i.e 100=100. But what I'm after is identifing any numbers that are greater than the value only 120 > 100.  I have tested if the values are being passed and they are.
What is my mistake here can anyone suss it out.

```
function validateoffhire(form) {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
  var test2Regex = /^[0-9 ]+(([\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/;


  var accumulator = 0;
  var num2 = num1.value;
  var i=0;
  var offhire1 = [];
  var pro2 =[];  
  for(var i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
    offhire1[i] = document.getElementById('offhire1' + i);
    pro2[i] = document.getElementById('pro2' + i);
    var offhire2 = offhire1[i].value;
    // var pro3 = pro2[i].value; 



    if(!offhire2.match(test2Regex)){
      inlineMsg('offhire1' + i,'This needs to be an integer',10);
      return false;
    }
    else if (offhire1[i].value > pro2[i].value) {
      alert("You entered: " + pro2[i].value)

      inlineMsg('offhire1' + i,'You have off hired to many items',10);
      return false;
    }   
    else{
      accumulator += parseInt(offhire2);
    }
  }
  if(accumulator <= 0){
    inlineMsg('num1' ,'You have not off Hired any items',10);
    return false;
  }


  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow you.  If the numbers are the same, the statement won't match.

One issue in your code is that you're comparing strings, not numbers.  You may want to change it to:

```
(parseInt(offhire1[i].value) > parseInt(pro2[i].value))
```

Comment: Thank you cwolves. thats my mistake doh !